# Window bat script start java program loading dll failed, but successfully started using IntelliJ idea?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

```java
static {
    System.loadLibrary("tdfapi_jni");
    System.loadLibrary("TDFAPI30");
}
```

I have placed these two dlls in the system32 directory.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it, specified the path of the dll in the script.

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" %JAVA_OPT% -Djava.library.path=dll
```